# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null on multiple file upload

Tags: php, laravel-4.2

I want to upload multiple files to directory and  inert into table, but I am getting the following error:

```
Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null
```

Below is my code:

***controller***

```
$editLogistic = LogisticTransaction::find($id);
$batchid = $editLogistic->id;

if(Input::file('attachment')) {
    foreach(Input::file('attachment') as $image) {
        $filename =  date("Ymdhis")."-".uniqid();
        $filename = $filename.".".$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $path=public_path('logistic/images');
        $x= $image->move($path,  $filename);

        DB::table('logistic_batch_attachment')->insertGetId(array(
            'batch_id'     =>  $editLogistic->id,
            'filename'     =>  $filename,
            'path_to_file' =>  $path,
        ));
    }
}
```

***view***

```
{{
    Form::open(array(
        'url'=>'jlogistic/edit/'.$logistic->id,
        'class' => 'form-horizontal',
        'files' => true,
        'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data','method'=>'post'
    ))
}}

<div class="form-group increment">
    <label  class="col-lg-2 control-label">Attachment</label>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="file" name="attachment[]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group-btn"> 
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add
            </button>
        </div>
</div>
```

I am getting this error but file are moving to folder and inserting into database:

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

Comment: check if `Input::file('attachment')` is array

Comment: Please add the code for getClientOriginalName()

Comment: @vpalade yes it is array

Comment: @Penguine what code?

Comment: Code for the function getClientOriginalName()

Comment: It seems that your function getClientOriginalName() is expecting some parameter, but is receiving null. Now, since the images are getting inserted and moving to folder, the best assumption can be, your foreach loop's last iteration is on null